# Find the smallest value in a list or array pointed out by specified indexes

Tags: excel, vba

I have a list of 200+ numbers (waste from different sizes of steel tools used on a lot of different raw material sizes, I'm trying to find the optimal combination of six tools that give the least waste if used on all raw material sizes). I have the combination of items that give the least waste and their position (index) in the list (say index number 7, 12, 9, 8, 10, and 11 as an example)

Now I need to figure out which of these indexes point to the smallest item in the list. (i.e. I need the formula to return the index itself, for example 9 in the example above, if that index points to the smallest value of the six values pointed out)

I can't just use a regular MIN() on the entire list to get the smallest value and then MATCH() to find the index, since the same waste figure may be found at some other index not in the list, and those are no good (that's what I started with but found it pointed to non-optimal tools sometimes). 
Sound like an easy problem at first (and maybe it is!?) but I can't seem to find a working solution (and I don´t want to use VBA to solve this unless I have to).

Any ideas?

(see the red erroneous index returned in this example)

[image]

Comment: Would you mind terribly if you amended this to include less bumph and a bit more detail on the mathematics? I'm having trouble thinking about the objective function that you need to construct to solve this.

Comment: I tried to get it in somehow, but that was also hard (new to stackoverflow..) :-)

Comment: A regular MATCH(MIN(I6:I22);I6:I22;0) won't work since duplicates may exist in the list I6:I22. I was aiming for something like =MATCH(MIN(INDEX(I6:I22;{7;12;9;8;10;11};1));C2:H2;0) where the figures in brackets of course should be references to the index list and C2:H2 is the reference to the index numbers. This does not work though. Not sure if this clarifies the question..?

Comment: Not really for me. But do feel free to keep it as it is for now and see if any other the other scientific programmers on this site pick it up. If not, then do repose it and I'll take a look.

Comment: I'm afraid it's not very clear to me either. Perhaps a smaller, mocked-up example with dummy data in which you indicate your desired results will help clarify.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [AGGREGATE¹ function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/AGGREGATE-function-43B9278E-6AA7-4F17-92B6-E19993FA26DF) achieves minimum values with its [SMALL](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SMALL-function-4050a82e-659a-4ef6-a970-c963a6f69c29) sub-function (**15**) and a *k* of 1. Forcing any non-matching rows into an error and discarding those errors with option **6** will get you the minimum of the matching tools' values. Another AGGREGATE match to discount any matches to the minimum but not the tool selection will produce the correct results.

[image: Aggregate min conditions]

The formula in C4 is,

```
=INDEX($A$6:$A$22, AGGREGATE(15, 6, ROW($1:$17)/((C$6:C$22=AGGREGATE(15, 6, C$6:C$22/(ROW($1:$17)=$C$2:$H$2), ROW(1:1)))*(ROW($1:$17)=$C$2:$H$2)), 1))
```

[image]

Fill right as necessary.

---

**Conditional Formatting for cell highlighting**

The conditional formatting to show a light grey background fill that indicates the Tool Indexes (a6:A22) that match the subset of tools in C2:H2 was created by selectin A6:J22 then creating a CF rule based upon teh following formula,

```
=ISNUMBER(MATCH($A6, $C$2:$H$2, 0))
```

The conditional formatting rule that highlights the appropriate filtered minimum value was created by first selecting C6:J22 and using the following formula for a CF rule,

```
=$A6=C$4
```

This last CF rule may seem simplistic but there is no reason to reprocess the nested calculation once the answer was arrived upon.

---

¹ <sub>The [AGGREGATE function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/AGGREGATE-function-43B9278E-6AA7-4F17-92B6-E19993FA26DF) was introduced with Excel 2010. It is not available in earlier versions.</sub>

Comment: WOW! Jeeped, that was quite impressive! Works like a charm (but I could just remove the INDEX as the nested AGGREGATE function produces the same index I need). It took me a while just to crack what the h*ll was going on in that formula but when I got it I feel I definetely learned something today! Thanks a bunch!

Comment: Yes, the INDEX was there to recover whatever was actually in A6:A22 with AGGREGATE returning the relative position; coincidentally, the relative position matches the actual cell value. If *Tool A, Tool B*, etc were in A6:A22, then INDEX would have to be reinstated.

Comment: btw, those cell highlights in the image were created by conditional formatting in my sample workbook. Drop a comment if you want the formulas for them.

Comment: Sure, why not - if not just so I can confirm if it´s tha same way I would have done it (or so that someone else in this forum can use it :-) )